# BlackBerry HttpConnection Content of URL

Tags: html, http, url, blackberry, httpconnection

I make HttpConnection by the following way:

```
try {
   StreamConnection s = (StreamConnection)Connector.open(url);
   HttpConnection httpConn = (HttpConnection)s;                             
} catch (Exception e) {
   Dialog.alert(e.getMessage());
}
```

How can I get the content of the url (the text inside the url html file)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Thry something like this:

```
 StreamConnection c = null;
 InputStream s = null;
 byte[] response;
 try {
     c = (StreamConnection)Connector.open(url);
     s = c.openInputStream();
     response = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(s);
 } finally {
     if (s != null)
         s.close();
     if (c != null)
         c.close();
 }
 String html = new String(response);
```

Comment: Note this is a simplified code. It should also handle possible exceptions in a `catch` block. As well as it assumes the encoding of the data is BB default "ISO-8859-1".

Comment: BTW, why do you use `StreamConnection`? Maybe just use `HttpConnection`?

Comment: What is the difference between using StreamConnection and using HttpConnection? Or this is the same? I mean .. is StreamConnection better or faster than HttpConnection? Because I never worked on StreamConnection before. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I receive NullPointerRxception

Comment: What is the difference between using StreamConnection and using HttpConnection? Or this is the same? I mean .. is StreamConnection better or faster than HttpConnection? Because I never worked on StreamConnection before. Thanks

Comment: As you I've never worked with `StreamConnection`, so I'd prefer to use `HttpConnection`. As to NPE - please show your resulting code and point to the line where exactly you get the NPE.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this by the following link.........

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Want-to-get-Response-from-the-particular-URL/m-p/1291627#M172814